# How to display data on another wordpress multi sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having multi stores (etsy kind) using woocommerce product vendors on my wp single site and I'd like to display the vendor list on my another wp multi sites. Also whenever a vendor link is clicked, it should open up its sub page created on single site.

Any approaches for doing that?

Comment: If all you're doing is displaying a vendor list you could look into the json API and write a specific request handler for that. I wouldn't go through the whole multi site process for just a vendor list

Comment: Hi Kai Qing, I'm having separate sites because I intend to split data. Single site which handles all users data and multi sites are mainly for blogging/posting purposes for several countries. But somehow in certain post I may need to cross reference data. Any better idea?

Comment: You can still use the json API in multi site. Alternatively, you can just write a custom plugin to specifically fetch the needed data. WP makes this very easy.